# Bash list datetime between two dates

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How to list all datetimes in the format `"+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"` ?

This only prints the dates, but I want the time included as well i.e. `2016-07-20 08:33:21`

```
start=2013-09-05 
end=2013-09-11

   while [[ $start < $end ]] 
     do 
      printf "$start\n"; start=$(date -d "$start + 1 day" +"%Y-%m-%d") 
     done
```

Comment: I may be missing something obvious here but why don't you just add those extra parts to the format string?

Comment: I did, "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" got an error: `08:33:21: command not found`

Comment: `date +"%F %T"` should work fine. (`%F` and `%T` are just shortcuts for the date and time formats you are using).

Comment: Where should the hours, minutes and seconds come from?

Comment: Another thing to be aware of is the fact that you shouldn't be passing the variable as the first argument to `printf`. You should instead pass a format string, e.g. `printf '%s\n' "$start"`.

Comment: `$start + 1 day` doesn't do what you think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this one can help you:

```
#!/bin/bash

start="2016-07-20 08:33:50"
end="2016-07-20 08:34:01"

while [[ $start < $end ]]; do
    echo $start
    secs=$(date +%s --date="$start")
    start=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' --date="@$((secs + 1))")
done
```

Output:

```
2016-07-20 08:33:50
2016-07-20 08:33:51
2016-07-20 08:33:52
2016-07-20 08:33:53
2016-07-20 08:33:54
2016-07-20 08:33:55
2016-07-20 08:33:56
2016-07-20 08:33:57
2016-07-20 08:33:58
2016-07-20 08:33:59
2016-07-20 08:34:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this;

```
#!/bin/bash
start=2013-09-05 
end=2013-09-11

while [[ $start < $end ]] 
 do 
   start=$(date -d "$start + day + minute" +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") 
   printf "$start\n"; 
 done
```

Comment: You could, but the output would start from a different point and the hours, minutes and seconds would always be 00:00:00.

Comment: "$start + day +hour" or  "$start + day +minute" or "$start +second"